# Construct boost::type_erasure::any from C string but store as std::string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, boost, boost-type-erasure

Is it possible to declare a [`boost::type_erasure::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_typeerasure.html) in a way that constructing and assigning from string literal or `char const*` automatically copies the string into a `std::string` and stores that in the `boost::type_erasure::any` object?

By default, a `boost::type_erasure::any` just stores the string pointer.

The aim is to avoid a source of errors when users of my `any` type assign a string pointer to it, assuming a copy will be made (like `std::string` does) and then the lifetime of the string ends before my `any` is read, causing a crash.

Example:

```
#include <boost/type_erasure/operators.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/any.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/any_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/relaxed.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>

#include <iostream>

namespace te = boost::type_erasure;

using my_any = te::any< boost::mpl::vector<
    te::copy_constructible<>,
    te::destructible<>,
    te::typeid_<>,
    te::relaxed
    /* I believe some changes here would do the trick */
    >>;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Store an std::string by explicitly calling string constructor.
    my_any a = string("abc");

    // The following should copy-construct an std::string too but it just stores
    // the string pointer.
    my_any b = "abc";

    // Works as expected.
    cout << te::any_cast<string>( a ) << endl;

    // This crashes because the underlying type of b is not std::string.
    // With some changes to the my_any type this shouldn't crash anymore.
    cout << te::any_cast<string>( b ) << endl;
}
```

[Live Demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e26af8f405ddc4b3)

Answer (score 0):

No, `any` stores anything.  `const char*` is anything.

Note that `"hello"s` is a literal of type `std::string`.

Comment: You should mention that `"hello"s` works only in C++14 and above.

Comment: I was hoping to do that without "s" suffix, as it is just syntactic sugar for calling `std::string` constructor. The aim is to avoid a source of error when users of `my_any` assign string pointers to it, assume a copy will be made (like `std::string` does) and then the lifetime of the pointer ends before `my_any` is read, causing a crash.

Comment: @zett42 You should never ever get a type out of an any without first checking it or proving it is that type.  You should never ever put a type in an any without letting the person taking it out prove what it is.  If you want an enumerated set of types, consider variant.  If you want to support anything put into the any must be convertible to string (or even must be optionally convertible to string with runtime checked failure), you could probably do that.

Comment: @Yakk _first checking it or proving it is that type_ ...sure I will be doing that. At the same time I don't want to exclude users from providing string literals. I could hide the `any` behind a templated "setter" that takes a static type and provide a specialization for `char const*` that converts to `std::string` before storing in `any`. Though I think `any` could do this conversion automatically if the right concepts are provided (something along the lines of [this example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure/any.html#boost_typeerasure.any.construction)).

Comment: I have posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42845009/7571258) that hopefully clarifies the intended use of the `any`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting an answer to my own question in the hope to clarify the intended use of the `boost::type_erasure::any` without making the original question too verbose.

This answer shows a possible workaround by hiding the `boost::type_erasure::any` behind the interface of another class and providing an overload of a setter method for all types convertible to `std::string`. This overload takes care about converting char pointers and char arrays to `std::string`.

I think one additional overload is not that bad, but ideally I would like to avoid that boilerplate and make the `any` type aware of how to convert C strings. That brings us back to my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42837888/7571258).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

#include <boost/type_erasure/operators.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/any.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/any_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/type_erasure/relaxed.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>

namespace te = boost::type_erasure;

// A class to store attributes of any type by name.
class Attributes
{
public:
    using Key = std::string;

    // A type that can store any value (similar to std::any).
    using AnyValue = te::any< boost::mpl::vector<
        te::copy_constructible<>,
        te::destructible<>,
        te::typeid_<>,
        te::relaxed
        >>;

    // Overload for all types that ain't strings.
    template< typename T >
        std::enable_if_t< !std::is_convertible<T, std::string>::value, 
    void > SetAttr( Key const& name, T&& value )
    {
        m_attr.insert_or_assign( name, std::forward<T>( value ) );
    }

    // Convert to std::string for all convertible types
    // (char pointer and char array included).
    template< typename T >
        std::enable_if_t< std::is_convertible<T, std::string>::value, 
    void > SetAttr( Key const& name, T&& value )
    {
        m_attr.insert_or_assign( name, std::string( std::forward<T>( value ) ) );
    }

    template< typename T >
    T GetAttr( Key const& name ) const 
    { 
        return te::any_cast<T>( m_attr.at( name ) ); 
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<Key, AnyValue> m_attr;
};
```

The following example shows how different kind of strings can be passed to `Attributes::SetAttr()` and be queried generically via `Attributes::GetAttr<std::string>()`:

```
using namespace std;

Attributes a;
// Works even w/o special care.
a.SetAttr( "key1", string("foo") );

// Without the SetAttr() overload for strings, user would have to remind 
// to cast back to char const* when calling MyClass::GetAttr().
a.SetAttr( "key2", "bar" );

// Without the SetAttr() overload for strings, a later call to GetAttr()
// would cause a crash because we are passing pointers to temporary objects.
{
    // test arrays
    char temp1[] = { 'b', 'a', 'z', 0 };
    a.SetAttr( "key3", temp1 );
    char const temp2[] = { 'b', 'i', 'm', 0 };
    a.SetAttr( "key4", temp2 );

    // test pointers
    a.SetAttr( "key5", &temp1[0] );
    a.SetAttr( "key6", &temp2[0] );
}

try
{
    // When getting a string attribute we no longer have to care about how it was
    // passed to SetAttr(), we can simply cast to std::string in all cases.
    cout << "'" << a.GetAttr<string>( "key1" ) << "'" << endl;
    cout << "'" << a.GetAttr<string>( "key2" ) << "'" << endl;
    cout << "'" << a.GetAttr<string>( "key3" ) << "'" << endl;
    cout << "'" << a.GetAttr<string>( "key4" ) << "'" << endl;
    cout << "'" << a.GetAttr<string>( "key5" ) << "'" << endl;
    cout << "'" << a.GetAttr<string>( "key6" ) << "'" << endl;
}
// boost::type_erasure::bad_any_cast or std::out_of_range
catch( std::exception& e )
{
    cout << "Error: " << e.what() << endl;
}
```

[Live Demo.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BubQfCaN9ZnfOx0M)

Comment: `SetAttr` should take `T&&` not `T const&` to permit move-in (assuming your version of any supports it)

Comment: @Yakk Thanks, I've updated the code according to your suggestion.